# Prompt to re-logging with credentials using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

We have setup a web application with about 40 ajax calls on a LAMP(hP) system. We are keeping track of users using PHPSESSION with a 1 hour cookie life (this cannot change, we want a quick expiration).
**PROBLEM:** If a user is afk for that 1 hour and the window is up and he attempts to use the web app it will just deny all Ajax calls because of an expired cookie session and server returns "Permission denied"

**Question:** Besides editing all 40 $.ajax calls and including a check for permission and show a relog form is there a global way or better way to implement an Ajax Relog Form accross the whole system?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a useless call like `keep_alive()`. This function does nothing but you call it every 40 minutes so the session does not expires.

Comment: No, for security reasons we want the users to log back on, I am just looking if there is a better way then editing all 40 ajax calls